# Postman when testing POST returning Status 200 is body returns error

Tags: postman

Is it possible that the status 200 is referring to the http only. Eg that it connected and authentication was correct but the post business logic itself is wrong?

If so what need to be changed to have the Status also Teton a 400 for a bad post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send only one status code, so either 200 or 400. You can send back a custom reply with code 200 and the error description in it if you want though.

Comment: Thank you.  My code should be 400 because the body has an error but I am receiving a 200 and don’t understand why